ESLint couldn't determine the plugin "import" uniquely
I am trying to commit the code to git and getting this problem:
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.50.0

ESLint couldn't determine the plugin "import" uniquely.

- /Users/krish/Documents/frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/eslint-plugin-i@2.27.5-4\_@typescript-eslint+parser@6.7.4_eslint@8.50.0_typescript@4.8.4__eslint@8.50.0/node_modules/eslint-plugin-i/lib/index.js (loaded in ".eslintrc.cjs » @antfu/eslint-config » @antfu/eslint-config-vue » @antfu/eslint-config-ts » @antfu/eslint-config-basic » plugin:import/recommended")

- /Users/krish/Documents/frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/eslint-plugin-i@2.27.5-4\_@typescript-eslint+parser@6.7.4_eslint@8.50.0_typescript@5.0.4__eslint@8.50.0/node_modules/eslint-plugin-i/lib/index.js (loaded in ".eslintrc.cjs » @antfu/eslint-config » @antfu/eslint-config-vue » @antfu/eslint-config-ts » @antfu/eslint-config-basic » ./standard")

Please remove the "plugins" setting from either config or remove either plugin installation.

If you still can't figure out the problem, please stop by https://eslint.org/chat/help to chat with the team.

How can I resolve this?
I tried using different versions, making changes in package.json but the still issue appears.
{
  "name": "quizizz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "packageManager": "pnpm@8.6.2",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "turbo run build",
    "build-join": "turbo run build --filter=join",
    "build-practice": "turbo run build --filter=practice",
    "build-practice-dev": "turbo run build-dev --filter=practice",
    "dev": "FORCE_COLOR=1 turbo run dev ",
    "dev-admin": "FORCE_COLOR=1 turbo run dev --force --filter=admin --log-prefix=none",
    "dev-join": "FORCE_COLOR=1 turbo run dev --force --filter=join",
    "dev-practice": "FORCE_COLOR=1 turbo run dev --filter=practice",
    "dev-qtility": "FORCE_COLOR=1 turbo run dev --filter=qtility",
    "dev:support-hub": "FORCE_COLOR=1 turbo run dev --filter=support-hub... --log-prefix=none",
    "local": "FORCE_COLOR=1 VITE_NODE_ENV=local turbo run dev",
    "local-admin": "FORCE_COLOR=1 VITE_NODE_ENV=local turbo run dev --filter=admin --log-prefix=none",
    "lint": "turbo run lint",
    "lint:ci": "turbo run lint:ci",
    "lint:ci-diff": "turbo run lint:ci-diff",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx,md}\"",
    "commit": "cz",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "docs:build": "turbo run docs:build --filter=docs",
    "docs:dev": "turbo run dev --filter=docs",
    "admin-e2e": "sh ./scripts/run-admin-e2e.sh",
    "join-e2e": "sh ./scripts/run-join-e2e.sh",
    "diff-test": "sh ./scripts/run-diff-tests.sh",
    "check-circular": "sh ./scripts/check-circular-dependencies.sh"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.635.0",
    "admin": "^1.4.1",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "1.44.1",
    "@snyk/github-codeowners": "1.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.4.2",
    "commitizen": "4.3.0",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "3.3.0",
    "danger": "^12.3.3",
    "eslint": "8.50.0",
    "eslint-config-custom": "workspace:eslint-config-custom",
    "git-commit-msg-linter": "4.8.3",
    "husky": "8.0.0",
    "madge": "7.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.7",
    "turbo": "1.10.7",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
}

eslint config
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  // This tells ESLint to load the config from the package `eslint-config-custom`
  extends: ["custom"],
};

I have added the package.json and eslint file (this is from my root directory), I also tried to remove node modules and renistall it but still it persist.

Help us help you - share you package.json and your eslint configuration

added in the question, please check

This is covered in the ESLint FAQs, https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/troubleshooting/couldnt-determine-the-plugin-uniquely:

When using the legacy ESLint config system, you may see this error running ESLint after installing dependencies:
...
Common resolutions for this issue include:

Upgrading all versions of all packages to their latest version
Running npm dedupe or the equivalent package manager command to deduplicate packages, if their version ranges are compatible
Using overrides or the equivalent package manager package.json field, to force a specific version of a plugin package

Note that this may cause bugs in linting if the plugin package had breaking changes between versions




You'll likely want to add eslint-plugin-import as a devDependency, so that all consumers of it resolve to the same version. Right now, as stated in the error message, you're getting two different versions of it within your node_modules/.
We should also note you're using an outdated version of ESLint (8.x instead of 9.x) and the legacy config system. See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files for the new "flat" config system. Flat config makes it easier to have workspace custom configs & plugins, which might help you here too.
